# Google Apps Scripts - Exception

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function moveFiles(sourceFile, targetFolder) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFile);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolder);
  file.moveTo(folder);
}
```

When running this code i am getting the error:

Exception: Invalid argument: id
moveFiles   @ Code.gs:16

I have turning off disabling Chrome V8 runtime. However throws up a serer error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the line of the error `Exception: Invalid argument: id moveFiles @ Code.gs:16` in your script? And, in your script, what are the values of `sourceFile` and `targetFolder`?

Comment: Line 3 is throwing the error : var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolder);

Comment: The values are the Ids of the file and folder. 
For example "0MsqBuDUH5N7YwHHlqntQltsWxQVZMO1q" & "1p1umToIrE-gieg22KSS8rfo5LUJ0oS41"

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that when `1p1umToIrE-gieg22KSS8rfo5LUJ0oS41` of `targetFolder` is the valid folder ID of the folder you can access, `var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolder);` can work. So, how about confirming the folder and folder ID again?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I have sorted it, I was using them the wrong way round!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Yes will do thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the File ID I was feeding the script was incorrect.